# How to call a redis command and send output to a file?

Tags: python, redis

I want to run a redis command using a python script like:

```
redis-cli hget "User-123"
```

And I want the output to be written to a file.

I cannot actually install the redis client because this script has to have no dependancies.

I have python 2.6.6

Comment: You should just be able to send the encoded query using the Redis protocol http://redis.io/topics/protocol

Answer (score 0):

Use [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py), it works with 2.6.  Then use python's builtin [file i/o](https://docs.python.org/2.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) functions to write to a file.